# Save vs. Submit vs. Done vs. "Specific Action"

Tags: copywriting

I am working on a Web Application (not a website with forms). It is a fairly exhaustive system with 250+ unique pages design. It has pages/sections/ settings where the main “actions” to be performed are typically as

- Save/ Save Tab/ Save Section
- Submit
- Update

Or another example is I have multiple settings options where I create many “New” entities –

- New Form
- New Customer
- New Rule
- Add New
- Add Account

I can opt for simplification and consistency – But I land up on counter intuitive scenarios where I click “Add New” and end up Deleting/ Banning some entity.

I classify buttons into broad 2 categories –

- Most Likely Desired Action – Save, Submit, Apply
- Housekeeping – Reset, Revert, Cancel

Any tips on adopting a naming convention for growing Web Application?

Answer (score 2):

You're right to consider it, and to favour consistency.

Being consistent should **absolutely not mean that "add new" deletes** anything - I cannot see how that arose.

'Update' is nice because it has the connotation that it is a repeatable action. As long as this is true, then it is more desirable than the intimidating 'Submit' and all the fear of incorrect data entry that goes with it.

Your new entities have commonality in 'Add New' - I would suggest implementing 'Add New' *only* where "new what?" is blindingly obvious, and in places with multiple possible new entries - 'Add New Column', 'Add New Row', 'Add New Account', etc.

Avoid this with 'Update' though - it is far nicer UX to be able to modify multiple entries before updating them as a whole.

Be as general as possible, and stick to it where you can. But **never ever ever** blindly stick to a naming convention for conventions sake, above all else, at the expense of names making sense.

If you take your scheme to the point where "add" deletes something ***then you're implementing it wrong.***